# Data Model to represent Flat and Variable rate

Tags: sql, database, datamodel

I am designing a database for an app to sell parking spot use. Customer can order n number of uses of parking spot uses or pay a flat rate and use it for monthly/weekly or yearly. They can do mix of those also. Like they can buy 9 parking spot uses and later decide they will pay for the whole month - in which case their charges are kind of pro-rated.
For this, I have a Customer table, an Order Table and then an order type table. However, I am having a slightly hard time with the order-type table.

Can some one please shed light on how to model the rate and get available spot-uses for a customer?

Comment: Post whatever schema you have so far.  Also indicate how these tables will be used.

Comment: Where does the variable rate come into play?  All I read are various flat rates.  Also, how would you explain your pricing scheme to a customer in simple and easy to understand terms?  If you can't do that, then you probably need to spend a bit more time understanding the business before trying to model it.